# Flex 3 - ActionScript - Cairngorm DispatchEvents - Como saber quando evento finalizou?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe-flex

Estou usando o Flex 3 com Cairngorm framework. Em algum lugar do programa eu disparo um evento `dispatchEvent`, como:

```
CairngormEventDispatcher.getInstance().dispatchEvent(new eventExample [...]
```

Tem alguma maneira de saber quando o evento finalizou? Que está 100%?

Porque eu tenho outras coisas depois dessa chamada que dependem do retorno desse evento. Por exemplo, um arrayCollection de itens que retornam da base com esta chamada. Mas na primeira chamada que está num popWindow ele trás nulo, porque não finalizou o evento ainda e eu acabo usando o array para outras coisas.. Quando eu abro a tela denovo lá está os dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente ao despachar um novo evento de um objeto o único ouvinte que escuta este evento é adicionado no próprio objeto.

#### Exemplo no Flash:

```js
var objeto:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); //Cria o objeto
objeto.addEventListener("CONTADOR_10", funcaoOuvinte); //Adiciona um ouvinte ao objeto

var contador:int = 0;
for(var i:int = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    contador++;
    trace(contador);
    if(contador == 10) {
        objeto.dispatchEvent(new Event("CONTADOR_10", false, false)); //Despacha um novo evento chamado "CONTADOR_10";
        break;
    }
}

function funcaoOuvinte(e:Event):void {
     trace("Evento concluído/escutado com sucesso!");
}
```

No exemplo acima, eu adiciono uma função que é executada somente quando todo meu código estiver pronto e despachado com o evento chamado *"CONTADOR_10"*.

Não tenho muitos conhecimentos sobre esta biblioteca, mas notei que ela possui o `addEventListener`, responsável por adicionar ouvinte de eventos ao objeto `CairngormEventDispatcher.getInstance()`.

Tente adicionar seu código na função ouvinte:

```
CairngormEventDispatcher.getInstance().addEventListener("SEU_EVENTO", function():void {
    trace("Evento concluído");
}
```

Lembrando que sempre que adicionado um ouvinte e este não será mais usado, deve-se removê-lo com o `removeEventListener`.

Comment: biio realmente, adicionando o addEventListener ele espera até estar concluido. E o que aconteceu foi que, na primeira chamada ele nem entra no listener e não faz nada, só a partir da segunda chamada. O que eu fiz pra resolver pra quem tiver o mesmo problema é colocar minha lógica que estava depois da chamada na função result() do Command. Quem utiliza esse framework irá saber onde ele fica. Obrigado pela ajuda!